# How to get one single value from an SQL request in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm trying to display all the Products whose Category matches the $id I'm getting by clicking a specific Category.

I tried using the ->first() and ->pluck('name') functions

I tried doing this in the CategoriesController :

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $category = Category::where('id', $id)->pluck('name');
        $products = Product::where('categorie', $category)->get();
        return view('categories.show')->with('products',$products);
    }
```

> ErrorException Method links does not exist. (View:
>   C:\wamp64\www\gestionPointDeVente\resources\views\categories\show.blade.php)
>   (which is the page that displays all the products of that category)
>
> BadMethodCallException Method links does not exist. in Macroable.php
>   line 74

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Are you saving your product categories by name or by id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of for the Category you could be using route model binding so this :

```
public function show($id)
```

Can become this:

```
public function show(Category $category)
{
    // if you decide to keep the id you can uncomment the next line
    // $category = Category::find($id);

    // the product has the category name or id? 
    $products = Product::where('categorie', $category->name)->get();
    return view('categories.show')->with('products',$products);
}
```

Then the error says that you are missing a `links` method which exists if you use a pagination, but in your code you do not.

So this line:

```
$products = Product::where('categorie', $category->name)->get();
```

should become this:

```
$products = Product::where('categorie', $category->name)->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was indeed because of the pagination !

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$category = Category::where('id', $id)->first()->name;
```

`->first()` pulls the first item from the database as your entity, then you can use the entity's `name` property to access the name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $categoryName = Category::where('id', $id)->value('name');
    $products = Product::where('categorie', categoryName)->paginate();
    return view('categories.show')->with('products',$products);
}
```